# When Class A extends Class B and they both have the same Property

Tags: php, class, extends

I have class A and class B. where class A extends class B.

They both have the property $fields, where $fields is an array, like:

class A fields

```
public $fields = array( 'id'=>'', 'product'=>'', 'productXpath'=>'', 'price'=>'', 'priceXpath'=>'', 'currency'=>'', 'website_url'=>'', 'url_id'=>'', 'day'=>'', 'month'=>'', 'year'=>'', 'time'=>'', 'status'=>'' );
```

class B fields

```
public $fields = array( 'id'=>'', 'website'=>'', 'visits'=>'', 'plugin_id'=>'', 'status'=>'' );
```

Only the structure and values within the array are different.

I need to access both properties, how do i do this ?

Comment: can you post your code up as im a bit confused by this bit "Only the structure and values within the array are different."?

Comment: Couldn't you use `Product` class instead of `array()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

If you have control over class B, simply define a getter and make `$fields` private:

```
public function getFields() {
    return $this->fields;
}
```

Then in class A you can do:

```
public function getFields() {
    $parentFields = parent::getFields();
    // Do something with $parentFields
    return $this->fields;
}
```

If not, you'll have to give a different name to the `$fields` property in class A, so as not to lose the value of class B.

Comment: and what if class B extends class C ? how do i get the fields array from C ?

Comment: @Laurent: No, you can't http://codepad.org/lk8KaVuG Why is everybody upvoting? :?

Comment: but if the fields array is instansiated within class A then with the inheritance he could just do $this->fields dependant on the scope and modifiers of fields. We need to see the code to answer the question fully.

Comment: +1 @KingCrunch although its unfair to fully dismiss Laurents answer as we dont know the scope or modiffiers placed on $fields

Comment: @NicholasKing We know: See the question `public $fields = array(/* .. */);`

Comment: @KingCrunch, I have updated the answer, parent::$fields will indeed try to access a static variable, which will fail. I don't think this can be done in PHP so he will need to define a getter function.

Comment: @KingCrunch unless i'm missing something they already have access to all the arrays etc. instantiated within the scope of the class by just using the $this keyword.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian, with the method describe in my updated post, the chain of inheritance can be as long as you want and it will still work. But it depends whether you can implement this or not.

Comment: @NicholasKing You missed, that the op wants to overwrite the property, but wants to access the parents implementation. Therefore `$this` refers to `A::$fields` and never to `B::$fields`. Or in other words: `B::$fields` is _not_ in the scope of class `A` anymore. http://codepad.org/2NlCyMCE

Comment: @Laurent i dont think this will work the :: is a static call and getFields is not static

Comment: @KingCrunch thats crazy!! :: is used for static, constant, and overridden properties calls, just read the man page http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php.

Comment: @NicholasKing Good idea: See example #3 there ;) And ":: is used for [..] overridden properties calls" is only true for static properties.

Comment: @KingCrunch just seen. Php is crazy, some of the examples on that page, simply would not compile in a compiled language look at barss dot dev at gmail dot com 01-Jul-2008 03:47 example :-S

Comment: @NicholasKing First of all: PHP gets compiled into bytecode before execution (and it seems, that it compiles well). But regarding the example: Even if you call `A::func()` within an object of class `B` it is within an object of class `B` (obviously), thus `$this` already refers to exactly this object and therefore `$this->test` exists, because it is defined in class `B` and _we are_ in an object of class `B`. There is _absolutely_ no magic.

Comment: @KingCrunch I get php is compiled at runtime, i worked with it for ~8 years and love it as a language however have not touched it for the past 2 years as i have mainly been working in java and C#. Reverting the mind back to php is quite an exercise. I just find it has ALOT of idiosyncrasies like English language. In C# java class A would never compile as its a call to an undefined method.

Comment: this is a very tricky stuff, if i can do this, i will be able to develop a very very short code for multiple sql joins and others

Answer (score 1):

make the property as static

```
public static $fields = array(...);
```

and get access to the variable by

```
echo ClassName::$fields;
```

Comment: What is each instance of the class has a different value for `$fields`? Based on his example, it looks like it will hold a kind of database row, which implies each instance will have different values.

Comment: @ Laurent I have just given another choice. Everything depends on what he must do